# Can I change a wasteland explorers equipment?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Is there any way to make my wasteland explorer switch out the outfit he's wearing?

Answer (score 7):

Without recalling the explorer, **no**. Sometimes an explorer will change into an outfit they find, or equip a weapon they find, if it's better*, but this is fully automatic. They'll still bring back their previous equipment.

*Better doesn't always mean what you'd choose. E.g. an explorer will swap out their rusty laser (7 damage) for a 6-8 damage sawn-off shotgun they find.

Comment: Ugh, that's annoying. I found an outfit with better Luck on it, and I'd love to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

With the new update (not sure the version number) if your dweller found locations during their exploration you can access his weapon and outfit and change into anything you want.